# Damage Weapon Crystals for 5e (custom magic item)

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance

I am running a West Marches-style campaign and due to a lack of clerics and wizards enchanting weapons is beginning to be a hindrance on the party. As such I would like to create single use stored magic attacks which can be attached to physical weapons, much like [weapon crystals in dnd 3.5](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/3.5e_Magic_Weapon_Enhancements#Weapon_Crystals).

The mechanics are, the caster casts a damaging spell into a fresh crystal. Depending on the gold value of the crystal the player get a least, lesser or greater enchantment.

- least: the spell damage is rolled and when attuned to a weapon will release 2 points of damage each attack with the elemental damage the spell gave. when the rolled damage is used up, the crystal is destroyed.
- lesser: the damage spell is noted by nDx, with each attack using 1Dx until n is 0, where the crystal is destroyed
- greater: the entire spell is stored in the crystal, on hit the PC may use the crystal to release all the damage at once, the crystal is destroyed afterwards.

Is this a balanced attachment to mundane weapons compared to permanent magical weapons for 5e?

Comment: Balanced compared to what? It's obviously more powerful than a mundane weapon.

Comment: @Erik compared to permanent magic items, like +1 weapons. I will update to clarify

Comment: A more apt comparison would be to consumable magic items

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the mechanic here. I see the link you gave for weapon crystals, but I don't really know 3.5(is that a homebrew link or is that official content?)  Without having a clear understanding of how this works or what your balancing it against (other weapons, buffs) or how your game/world is set up, I think this is Unclear and not yet answerable.

Comment: There’s no way to answer a balance question without more information, and possibly not even with more information. Magic items aren’t balanced, they just are what they are. The only “balance” of magic items is relative to how easy they are to get, which is totally up to the DM, so not a standard thing we can compare. Do you have information that makes this answerable? Or a different question about these items that we can answer?

Comment: @NautArch: The "3.5" link the asker provided is indeed homebrew, as indicated at the top and bottom of that wiki page: "Back to Main Page → 3.5e Homebrew → Equipment"

Comment: @V2Blast while the link is from a homebrew page the item comes from the Magic Item Compendium for 3.5 released in 2007. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Item_Compendium I am working on rewording this question so it is answerable

Comment: That's not what weapon crystals did in 3.5, though.